# Open a new form from main form and use WebBrowser

Tags: c#, forms

I have a main form and I would like to click a button and have a webpage displayed in a new form using the WebBrowser control, this is what I have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 MyForm = new Form1();

        MyForm.ShowDialog();



        MyForm.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.twitter.com/");
    }
```

The main forms name is "Twitter", this is the error I get:  'Twitter.Form1.webBrowser1' is inaccessible due to its protection level.  Seems simple enough.  How can I do this?

Comment: (1) Make webBrowser1 a public member of the Form1 class. (2) AFAIK ShowDialog won't return until MyForm is closed.

Comment: @kol is correct, change it to `MyForm.Show()` if you mean for it to immediately go to the next line and navigate.  Of course, to _really_ do it right, you'd pass that URL as a parameter into the constructor for MyForm, store it in a private member, then call `Navigate` in the `Shown` method of `MyForm`.  Then you would not have to expose `webBrowser1` to the other class(es), and you could still use `ShowDialog()` and retain the ability to wait for `FormClosed()` to occur before proceeding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the WebBrowser in the designer.  In the Properties window, change the Modifiers property to "Public".

Comment: Ok.  Changed 'modifiers' to Public and got rid of the error, but the form never opens up?  I don't think I need the MyForm.ShowDialog(); line??

Comment: ShowDialog opens the window modally, so you don't reach the following line. Change it to Show()

Answer (score 1):

Go in your form's Designer.cs file and change

```
private WebBrowser webBrowser1;
```

**To this:**

```
public WebBrowser webBrowser1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Thank you everyone.  To clarify; to make this work I had to:

1. Select the WebBrowser in the designer. In the Properties window, change the Modifiers property to "Public".
2. Add MyForm.show();

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Form1 MyForm = new Form1();

       MyForm.Show();



       MyForm.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.twitter.com/");
   }
   ```